# Excel 2010: VB delete rows that do not contain certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I am trying to delete entire rows based upon them not containing a certain criteria this is what I currently have:

```
Sub Delete_consultants()
  Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Faith Jones" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Cathy Robbs" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Nick farmer" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

     If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Jane Till" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

     If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Jack White" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

     If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Dylan Smith" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

     If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Emma Long" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

     If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Nick Winter" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

     If (Cells(i, "H").Value) = "Niel West" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The issue being that this is currently deleting the people I want to keep. But i can't work out how to delete the others all the posts I have found have only 1 or 2 criteria you can set where I need 9!! Also if possible I can't seem to work it out, would be if the rows containing these names are moved from DirectLink to Infomation (they are in the same workbook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the test in a separate function to shorten the code. Here is my suggestion, take what you like from it

```
Function IsMember(v As Variant, vArray As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim vLoop As Variant
    For Each vLoop In vArray
        If v = vLoop Then
            IsMember = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next vLoop
End Function

Sub Delete_Consultants()
    Dim lLast As Long, i As Long
    Dim vConsultants As Variant
    lLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    vConsultants = Array("Faith Jones", "Cathy Robbs", "Nick Farmer", "Jane Till", _
        "Jack White", "Dylan Smith", "Emma Long", "Nick Winter", "Niel West")
    For i = lLast To 1 Step -1
        If IsMember(Cells(i, "H"), vConsultants) Then
        'if you want to do something with the others use this instead
        'If Not IsMember(Cells(i, "H"), vConsultants) Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            'or to copy
            'Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Information").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats great, works perfectly until i use the:'If Not IsMember(Cells(i, "H"), vConsultants) Then.......... then  the error Delete method range class failed comes up!

Comment: @Lozza1234 - hmm, if one works the other should work as well. Did you switch the `If`s or just uncomment the second one? If latter then comment the first one out. Also, since you are using unqualified calls to `Cells` you need to ensure you are on the right sheet when running the macro.

Comment: It's very strange as the error occurs once it has actually copmpleted, so I end up with the reamining rows I want and then it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub Delete_consultants()
  Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
  Dim v As Variant
   For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    v = Cells(i, "H").Value
    With Cells(i, "H")
    If v = "Faith Jones" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

    If v = "Cathy Robbs" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

    If v = "Nick farmer" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

     If v = "Jane Till" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

     If v = "Jack White" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

     If v = "Dylan Smith" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

     If v = "Emma Long" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

     If v = "Nick Winter" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If

     If v = "Niel West" Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
        GoTo botttom
    End If
botttom:
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```